# Trigger Click of Submit Button When Parent Is Clicked with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I have a submit button wrapped in a div. I want to trigger a click event on the submit button when the div is clicked. The problem is, this click event bubbles up and causes a stack overflow/infinite loop. When I try to stop propagation of the child click event, the issue is not resolved.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.container').click(function () {
    var input = $(this).find('input');
    input.trigger('click');
    input.click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

This still causes the stack overflow error. So does returning false:

```
$('.container').click(function () {
    var input = $(this).find('input');
    input.trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish here?I am little confused here because, if you want the whole div to be clickable then why have a button inside? Am I missing something here or understand the question correctly?

Comment: Good question, @Sai: The input is inside of a div that needs to have some :before styles applied to it which keeps the input from being clickable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bind button click event inside container click one. It should be this way

```
$('.container').click(function() {
    var input = $(this).find('input');
    input.trigger('click');
});

$('input').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('button clicked');
});
```

The problem with your code is that container click triggers inner button click before its respective click handler is even registered, so it have no chance to stop event bubbling.

Comment: Simple, 'why didn't I think of that' working solution. Thank you!